# "Козла забивать"

Tags: фразеология

Игру в домино, особенно, когда игроки со всей силы стучат костяшками о стол, называют "забивать козла". А почему именно козла? Интересно, откуда пошло это название?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цитата в тему:
//---------------
Есть несколько версий. Говорят, что домино изобрели в Италии. Там даже соревнования при дворе какого-то герцога устраивались. А для победителя готовили жаркое из козлятины. В простонародье говорили "забивали козла". Есть другая версия, согласно которой это выражение чисто русское и появилось у нас. Так вот в жестокие допетровские времена проигравшего рядили в козлиную шкуру и били палками, обычно заканчивалось летальным исходом. Так и говорили: забивали "козла". Есть и другая версия. Что будто был очень грубый помещик-самодур, который любил играть в домино со своими крепостными. Проигравшему давали кличку не иначе как "козел", а помещик проигравшего беспощадно бил плетьми.
Говорят что был еще кузнец мастер делать подковы и любитель играть в домино. Так вот он, если кто соглашался с ним сыграть, то он лошадь тому подковывал особыми гвоздями под названием "козлы". Такой "козел" имел зазубрины словно рога у козла, и держалась подкова на таком гвозде очень крепко. Поэтому когда шли делать подковы к тому мастеру, то говорили: "пошли забьем "козла".
Но некоторые думают, что выражение "забивать козла" появилось уже почти в наше время. В домино есть кодекс чести - гомосексуалист не имеет права играть в эту игру. Если мужчина боится играть в домино, дескать не хочу проигрывать, то это верный признак, что, как говорится, "на воре и шапка горит". А на зоне гомосексуалистов называют "козлами". И если там кто из них решится сыграть в домино, то его просто изобьют.
Источник: http://samlib.ru/f/fomalxgaut_m_b/domino.shtml
//---------------
Я за недостатком времени на подробное разбирательство замечу только, что тут перемешены версии реальные и совершенно фантастические. 
Мне ближе версия с побиением проигравших. Просто еще помню, что проигравших называли козлами. В те поры, когда это слово еще не было столь однозначно оскорбительным.